# how do I know what color from the theme in Angular Material (v17) is used for each component?

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I am trying to modify some Material components but I do not want to use ngdeep and i want to follow the Material guidelines as much as possible. How can I define a component theme so that I can modify specific colors? Meaning: how do I know how the colors I define on my palette will be applied in the components?

As an example, let's pick this:

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Fill form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

From this page https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components  I can see how some names are defined, but if I look at the color for, for example, the background of the input in the example above, it is not clear what color will get applied. Is it constant?
I can also see from inspecting the component that the color is:
var(--mdc-filled-text-field-container-color);
But I can't find where this is getting set.

I'd appreciate some insights, as I could not find browsing Material code.